# Any quick examples of a Normal Space but not $T_1$

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

So I am having trouble picturing a space that is Normal, but not $T_1$ (if it is, we call it $T_4$). All distinct points in a normal space can be contained in disjoint closed sets that can be separated by disjoint open sets. I am looking for maybe something simple like point sets $\tau_x = \{ \phi, X, \{a,c\},\{a\},\{c\} \}$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "All distinct points in a normal space can be contained in disjoint closed sets"...

Comment: Sorry I was using $\mathbb{R}$ as the model in my head when I wrote this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a space with the indiscrete topology and more than one point.  It is trivially normal since there are no nonempty disjoint closed sets, but it is not $T_1$.

Comment: You mean $X = \{a,b\}$ with $\tau = \{\phi, X \}$? Because $\phi \cap X = \phi$ are disjoint closed sets?

Comment: Because the containment $\phi \subset \phi$ and $X \subset X$ is not strict, it is not normal?

Comment: Yes, I mean the topology $\{\emptyset, X\}$.  I don't understand your other questions...

Comment: So I mean in your example you want to take $a \neq b$ and by construction $\{a \} \subset X$ and $\{b \} \subset X$, hence this is not T1. But for the only (disjoint) closed sets $\phi$ and $X$ are also contained in (disjoint) open sets $\phi$ and $X$ respectively, this is supposed to make this space Normal. But in Normality, isn't it required that the disjoint open sets to *strictly* contain the disjoint closed sets? Because we have $\phi \subseteq \phi$ and $X \subseteq X$

Comment: No, the inclusions are not required to be strict in the definition of normality.

Comment: I see okay.10char

Answer (score 0):

Take a set $X$ and $p \in X$ and define the excluded point topology on $X$

$$\mathcal{T} = \{X\} \cup \{A \subseteq X: p \notin A\}$$

This is $T_0$ but not $T_1$ (as $\{p\}$ is dense, not closed). And all non-empty closed sets, as complements of open sets, contain $p$, so there are no closed disjoint sets to separate at all.